# Can't quit (ending match) in Game Center

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, game-center

I'm working on a turn based iOS game using game center and right now I have my test account participating in six games in Game Center, but every time I try to quit one by swiping on it (which should really end the game because my test account is the only one in it) it removes the game from the table for a split second and then replaces it immediately and doesn't quit.

Here is my playerQuitForMatch function:

```
// Handle players leaving the match in and out of turn.
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController
                      playerQuitForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
    // If the player was the current participant, remove them from the next participants array.
    if ([match.currentParticipant.playerID isEqualToString:GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer.playerID])
    {
        NSMutableArray* nextParticipants = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[match participants]];
        [nextParticipants removeObjectIdenticalTo:[match currentParticipant]];

        // If they were the last player, end the match because it is empty.
        if ([nextParticipants count] == 0)
        {
            [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:match.matchData completionHandler:nil];
        }
        // Otherwise, remove them from the match and pass priority.
        else
        {
            [match participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit
                                   nextParticipants:nextParticipants
                                        turnTimeout:0.0f
                                          matchData:match.matchData
                                  completionHandler:nil];
        }
    }
    // If they weren't the current participant, just remove them from the match.
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray* nextParticipants = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[match participants]];
        [nextParticipants removeObjectIdenticalTo:[match currentParticipant]];

        // The player can't be the last person in the game if they aren't the active player.
        [match participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit withCompletionHandler:nil];
    }

    NSLog(@"playerquitforMatch, %@, %@", match, match.currentParticipant);
}
```

And here's the console output:

```
2013-05-04 13:16:13.180 XYZ Mobile[7799:c07] Authenticating local user...
2013-05-04 13:16:13.587 XYZ Mobile[7799:c07] Authentication changed: player authenticated.
May  4 13:16:13 folsom-wireless-153.dynamic2.rpi.edu XYZ Mobile[7799] <Info>: 13:16:13.597120 com.apple.AVConference: GKSConnSettings: set server: {
        "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
        "gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
        "gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
        "gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
    }
2013-05-04 13:16:21.380 XYZ Mobile[7799:c07] 101
2013-05-04 13:16:58.150 XYZ Mobile[7799:c07] New Game Button Pressed
2013-05-04 13:17:00.146 XYZ Mobile[7799:c07] playerquitforMatch, <GKTurnBasedMatch 0x949ece0    id:0a8b8246-1872-410e-b9ae-819a9a00d4ff status:Open message:(null) taken:(null) created:2013-04-24 23:32:35 +0000
current:<GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949ad50 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
participants:
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949ad40 - id:G:1759434517 (local player) status:Done outcome:Quit lastTurn:(null)>
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949ad50 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949f2b0 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949f2c0 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949f650 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949f660 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949bc20 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
        <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949bc30 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
    >, <GKTurnBasedParticipant 0x949ad50 - id:(null) status:Matching outcome:None lastTurn:(null)>
2013-05-04 13:17:08.523 XYZ Mobile[7799:c07] has cancelled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand you correctly that:
* the game is swiped in game center's built-in UI, not a custom one?
* the game in question has the player as the current participant?

I believe you have to set a match outcome for the unmatched players. If you do not, they will still be matched. So what will happen is that GC finds a person trying to join your game and then this person will see a game with 1 person that has quit, himself as the current participant and six unmatched players. With your code it can happen that someone joins the game and 7 people have already left! Yes GC is weird.

What you want to do to end the game is to set a match outcome for all players and then call

```
endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler:
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints in answer 1 above, I had a similar issue when the initiator of a two player match quit before taking their turn but player 2 received a match a quit player. I did the following in my "take turn function" to ensure player 2 could get the match deleted from their game centre view. There is a lot of code posted but the key things to do are:

1-send data to game centre because it currently may have insufficient information.

2-quit all players from match programmatically

3-end the match programmatically

4-remove the match from the game centre programmatically.

```
//CHECKING IF PLAYER HAS QUIT.

NSUInteger currentIndex = [match.participants indexOfObject:match.currentParticipant];

//find the next participant in the match
GKTurnBasedParticipant *nextParticipant;

//Note if player 1's turn result is (0+1) % 2 = 0 remainder 1, therefore nextIndex = 1 (i.e. player 2 on a zero based index)
//Note if player 2's turn result is (1+1) % 2 = 1 remainder 0, therefore nextIndex = 0 (i.e. player 1 on a zero based index)

NSUInteger nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % [match.participants count];

nextParticipant = [match.participants objectAtIndex:nextIndex];

//check to see if any of the participants has quit.
for (int i = 0; i < [match.participants count]; i++)
{
    nextParticipant = [match.participants objectAtIndex:((currentIndex + 1 + i) % [match.participants count ])];

    if (nextParticipant.matchOutcome != GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit)
    {
        NSLog(@"Player %@ has not quit", nextParticipant);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Next participant %@ has quit", nextParticipant);

        //because the initiator has quit before playing, player "2 i.e current player index 1" should send dummy data to game centre
        //to allow them to delete this from their game centre view otherwise the match cannot be deleted from their game centre
        if(currentIndex == 1)
        {

             //send dummy data as is no turn has been taken. This allows the functions below to be carried out.
            [self CallToSendPlayerTurnData];

            for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in match.participants)
            {
                 part.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit;
            }

            //then end the match
            [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:match.matchData completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
             {
                 if (error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Erro ending quit match %@", error.localizedDescription);
                     {

                     }
                 }
              }
             ];

          //then remove the match programatically otherwise players GC viewer cannnot do this.
            NSLog(@"%@", match.matchID);
            [match removeWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
             }
             ];

            //disable player buttons
            [self disablePlayerButtons ];

            //stop timing either player.
            self.playerTimerTurn = 0;

            self.playerturn = 3; //when player has quit

            [statusLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sorry, the intiator quit the match so it will now be deleted."]];


        }
        else
        {

            //disable player buttons
            [self disablePlayerButtons ];

            //stop timing either player.
            self.playerTimerTurn = 0;

            self.playerturn = 3; //when player has quit

            [statusLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sorry, a player has quit the match so it cannot be progressed."]];

        }


        return;
    }
}
///IF PLAYER HAS QUIT EXIT MATCH ELSE CONTINUE BELOW
```